# Integrating Silverlight 4.0 with SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2007

I created a simple Sharepoint web part which hosts a silverlight application. I created a user control which loads the usercontrol.ascx from the layouts path and loads it up.

```
public class SLSampleWP : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the silverlight user control here
    /// </summary>
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Title = "Silverlight Sample";

        //silverlight control
        Control ctrlSilverlight;

        //load the user control
        ctrlSilverlight = this.Page.LoadControl(@"/_layouts/SL.Samples/SL.Samples.AgeCategory.ascx");

        //add the control
        this.Controls.Add(ctrlSilverlight);

    }
}
```

**User Control (ascx)**

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
Silverlight Web Part
<br />
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="source" value="/_layouts/SL.Samples/Silverlight.Samples.xap" />
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50917.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
</div>
```

But I'm not getting the silverlight control rendered in the page. What could be the issue. I'm a naive in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you Register the MIME Types on IIS?

Register the MIME type for file extension .XAP and .XAML in IIS

Extension           MIME Type 
.xaml               application/xaml+xml 
.xap                application/x-silverlight-app